# Change WebStorm LiveEdit Port (63342)

Tags: intellij-idea, localhost, port, webstorm, liveedit

How can I change the port of the LiveEdit feature in WebStorm ?

The default port is 63342, so i can run my project from : `http://localhost:63342/PROJECT_NAME`.
but due to authentication issues I need to switch to another fixed port number.

Help please,
Thanks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### WebStorm 8

In WebStorm 8 follow menu (or press Shortcut Alt+F7):

> File -> Settings

**Category:**

> IDE Settings -> Debugger -> JavaScript

And there change "`Built-in server port`".

**Hint:**

If you have a firewall warning when starting WebStorm then you must uncheck the checkbox "`Can accept external connections`" inside the settings window.

### WebStorm 9, 10, 11

In newer WebStorm Versions you'll have to enter the Settings like explained above, but enter a different category.

**Category:**

> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Debugger

Comment: Does this no longer work in webstorm?  I can find the LiveEdit settings but doesn't show the port...?

Answer (score 9):

Default built-in server port can be configured in IDE - Settings/Debugger/javaScript/built-in server port.

Answer (score 6):

Well you will need to go onto chrome for this one. Firstly you need to go into extensions:

You can quickly do this by typing `chrome://extensions/` into your awesomebar, and then just hitting <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

Makee sure developer mode is enabled:

[image]

Click `options` underneath `Jetbrains IDE support`. It will open up a new window where you can change your port.

Comment: The intellij default port needs to be changed as well or the IDE wont be able to communicate with the browser.

Comment: 2020-10-08: "Chrome extension is not currently required for debugging/Live Edit. It doesn't work reliably in most recent Chrome versions (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-37230), and we recommend turning it off in Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Debugger | Live Edit, Use JetBrains IDE Support extension for debugging and Live Edit" https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360009763819/comments/360002287939

Answer (score 3):

Press Key `CTRL +ALT +S`

Or

Got to Menu `File->Settings->Build, Execution and Deployment-> Debugger`

[image: Jetbrain Idea builtin port for live edit]

Change the server port. Keep in mind, the port you are trying to use should be free.

If you want to see the live edit. You have to install the chrome extension.

[Install Jetbrain Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jetbrains-ide-support/hmhgeddbohgjknpmjagkdomcpobmllji?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog)

Go the option of IntelliJ idea extension. change the port here also for synchronization.

[image]

### Restart your IntelliJ idea for effect.

Answer (score 0):

Just a heads up to anyone coming here/struggling - for whatever reason, I had to change the JetBrains chrome extension to use `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` to get things working.

[image]