# Webstorm on default port

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webstorm

I used Webstorm v6. I have created a new project and tried the following link to run the project.

`http://localhost:63342/Test/index.html` and `http://localhost:63342/Test`

My test project has only one file called `index.html`

But i am getting the below page in chrome.

[image]

I followed this link "[Change WebStorm LiveEdit Port (63342)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19633778/change-webstorm-liveedit-port-63342)"  but I still get the same error.

Any help on this?

Update :

Project structure :

```
Test 
 -- index.html 
 / Controller 
 / Css
 /View
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following: Open your html file in webstorm -> go with the mouse to the upper right corner of the editor window -> there should appear browsericons -> click on one icon to open it with the correct port AND URL/PATH

NOTE: The path behind the port has to begin with the Project name...

Comment: Hi @marcel, The problem is i want to run it on the localhost. The reason is i am using Angular js. And it have some code to communicate with Server.

Comment: the above solution should start it on localhost:[default port]/ProjectName/pathToFile/file.html

Comment: can you tell us, your project structure?!

Comment: Is there (in "Test") a ".idea"-folder?

Comment: Yes. It has an idea folder having webstorm related stuffs

Comment: hmmm, this is strange. did you check, if the port is free? if not, try an other port...

Comment: How can i change the other port. Actually i have a VM i did the same on that but it is working. So how can i change the Port and check it

Comment: Also i have installed Pycharm :(

Comment: open webstorm -> help -> find action -> type "built-in server" -> select "built-in server port:" -> type other port -> Apply