# keep getting "? Something is already running on port 3000" when I do npm start on react app

Tags: javascript, macos, npm, terminal, server

I keep on getting "? Something is already running on port 3000" message in my terminal when I start up my react server when there is absolutely nothing running on my port 3000

What I have tried to solve with:

1. Restart the macOS.
2. checking my "http://localhost:3000" on chrome browser. (Nothing: This site can’t be reached)
3. Go to chrome://serviceworker-internals and chrome://appcache-internals, search for localhost:3000 (Nothing found)
4. I also tried almost every command lines I found on Google regarding this issue
5. I also created another express.js app, and it was successfully launch on port 3000 while React said there is something running on 3000. React on my computer just keeping thinking there is something running on port 3000.

[image: terminal]

[image: Chrome]

Comment: run `netstat -anp tcp | grep 3000` if you have a result for it then yo have some process running in that port

Comment: @deepakthomas I ran the code you gave me, nothing pop out. the terminal just return right back.

Comment: Why don't you just change the port you are running your react-app on?

Comment: @UtkarshPramodGupta doesn't really solve the issue, just avoids it.

Comment: **Linux solution**: Avoid using `ctrl+z` to terminate the react app. This occures for me when I terminate the app from terminal using `ctrl+z`. This doesn't terminate the process due to some reason. Instead if I terminate using `ctrl+c` or `ctrl+shift+c` all the processes of react are properly stopped and thus I don't get the error.  To kill the process for first time I used `kill -9 pid`

Answer (score 78):

If you are a windows user you can try using

```
npx kill-port 3000
```

in your console. I was having the same problem and it worked for me.

Not sure about MAC.

Comment: It works on Mac.

Comment: Working well on Mac as well.

Comment: after installing kill-port@2.0.1, it works!

Comment: Love this brute force approach.

Answer (score 34):

Open cmd and write this

> netstat -a -o -n

You will get list of active connections then find **3000** by hitting

> Cntrl + f

[image]

Copy the PID of that port and hit this command

> taskkill /F /PID PID_of_port

[image]

**Edit**
 This guide is for windows.

Comment: I'm a Mac user.

Comment: I did this but there is no  process using port 3000. However I still get the error

Answer (score 19):

As @khurram khan suggested terminating the process may be the best option for you,  This work for me on linux:

```
$ lsof -i tcp:3000
$ kill -9 PID
```

the first command should give you the PID number to enter in the second command as PID.

Answer (score 15):

Kill `Node.Js` process from Task Manager.

Step 1: Open Task Manager by clicking ctrl+shift+delete

Step 2: Open Prcesses tab

Step 3: Search for Node.JS process and right click on that then click on End Task

Step 4: Now you can start again.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me on windows pc. This one is for those are not seeing the port when you run this command `netstat -a -o -n` on your command prompt.

Open your command prompt in administrator mode and run this command

`net stop winnat`

you'll get this response:

`The Windows NAT Driver service was stopped successfully.`

Then you run this next:

`net start winnat`

then you will get this response:

`The Windows NAT Driver service was started successfully.`

once you do that. Start the react server and it would work. Same too if your backend server doesn't run on 3000

Comment: This! I wasted so much time because this was not upvoted sufficiently. The underlying error which is not shown is: [listen EACCES: permission denied in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59428844/listen-eacces-permission-denied-in-windows). But beware, it may break WSL2/HyperV

Comment: This did the trick for me.

Answer (score 7):

I had this problem on Mac and I solved by running:

```
npx kill-port 3000
```

Answer (score 5):

For me, this works every time (macOS): `sudo kill -9 $(sudo lsof -t -i:3000)`

Comment: This worked best for my Mac, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I had stuck with this one for few hours, and the end I had found the solution
There was incorrect mapping to the local host in the hosts file and didn't had any relation to the port taken something like

```
10.2.224.130    localhost
```

Just Change it back to

```
127.0.0.1        localhost
```

Host file locations
https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/

Comment: This was almost the solution for me. I had just commented that line out for some reason. Adding it back fixed the problem. Was almost going mad

Comment: @Mike same for me

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone comes across this and the above solutions didn't help, make sure your `/etc/hosts` has:

`127.0.0.1 localhost`

For some reason this was wiped from my hosts file and CRA's dependency for checking ports (`detect-port-alt`) checks `localhost:[PORT]` to see if it's available. If it errors out, you'll always get the "Something is already running..." error when checking a specific port but not when using a random port (since that's picked by the dependency).

Answer (score 1):

kill node.js from the background processes. that would soleve the probelem. alterntively, you could restart your system

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple. You can fix it in 2 easy steps.

1. Check your environment variables if there is a key/entry with name "PORT".
2. If found delete that entry or rename it to something else.

It turns out that some other program is using that variable. Usually when you start react-scripts it will look for an environment variable with that title PORT.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on linux you can try

```
pkill -f node
```

to terminate the processs

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs when a task is left running on the port properly killing it.
this error can occur on both ports. Your react app and your node server.

To solve this you can run the following commands.

```
netstat -anp tcp | grep 3000
```

This command in the terminal will give you the list of activities on port 3000

```
npx kill-port 3000
```

This command will kill all the running servers on port 3000.

Now if you have the same problem for your Node server. You can follow the same steps.

```
netstat -anp tcp | grep 5000
```

Then

```
npx kill-port 5000
```

You don't need the first command. it's just to list out the running activities on the port.

just change the port number for any other port number.

[This is the output you get after running the commands.
I am using Git bash on windows.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YK8Cc.png)

Answer (score 0):

**Date**: Sat 07, October 2020 
**Windows**: Microsoft Windows 10 Pro Build 19041 
**Node**: 12.16.1 
**NPM**: 6.14.8

Something similar was happening to me on my Windows machine.  Tried a lot of things suggested here on StackOverflow and other places.

In my case, I was following a [video course](https://www.udemy.com/course/react-the-complete-guide-incl-redux/learn/lecture/8090848#overview) that was suggesting adding `--script-version 1.1.5` (as illustrated below) when creating a new React app. 
`create-react-app app-name --scripts-version 1.1.5`

Here's the `package.json` scripts versions: 
**React**: 17.0.1 
**React DOM**: 17.0.1 
**React Scripts**: 1.1.5

After running the command `npm start` and typing `y` to try to use a different port, the terminal will stay stucked until it was canceled.

[image]

Then I created a new React app without `--scripts-version 1.1.5` and after trying to running it, it was still running into `Something is already running on port 3000` but after typing `y`, the app will run with no problem on a different port.

[image]

Here's the `package.json` scripts versions (when it was running successfully): 
**React**: 17.0.1 
**React-Dom**: 17.0.1 
**React-Scripts**: 4.0.0

Comment: Changing the port itself doesn't really solve the issue tho... This is caused by a "probably" unused process that needs to be killed anyway. Changing the port will make the app run on a different port, but the default 3000 port will still be stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with the reason you do not see anything on *localhost:3000*, is because there must be a proper webapp or a website/server running on that port, but the *port:3000* is currently running some process, just not of a server/site/app.

This out of the way, depending on your type of OS, it is quite easy to check if there is in-fact a process on *port:3000* or not. For MacOS, opening a *terminal* and running `sudo lsof -i ':3000'` will list the current process on port 3000.
**Note that we need to run command as sudo or root**

Once you see what process is running, note the PID and run `kill -9 {PID}`, which should kill the process with PID (i.e distruptive process on *port:3000*). Now doing a `npm start` should get your app built, compiled and served on *localhost:3000*

Mostly what might've happened is that you had a `npm start` running which you either interrupted, or closed in the foreground. Doing a `fg` in your terminal will open any background tasks, so if this opens a `npm start` instance, it was this process stopping your flow. You can then properly end the session making sure all processes on *port:3000* are killed.

Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

for window use this in package.json
"start": "set PORT=3006 && react-scripts start"

for Linux and MacOS
"start": "PORT=3006 react-scripts start"

Answer (score 0):

For MAC :

lsof -i :3000
[image]

kill -9 7233

Here that port will be available after that. We can re-check again with lsof -i :3000 this command.

Answer (score -1):

**Simple and Easy solution**

close your current terminal and open a new one.

> If you are running it in VS Code just create a new terminal and delete the old one.

Comment: Hi @waqasali, This does not answers the question.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -4):

On **React** - you can run an already created React single-page application (SPA) by

**npm start** command.

That may start your locally hosting development server and runs your app at:

**http://localhost:3000/** which is equivalent to: **127.0.0.1:3000** address

**127.0.0.1** is the default localhost IP number while the default port number set by

**[create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-bootstrap)** package is **3000.**

When getting: **“Something is already running on port 3000**" failure error message you may think that the port captured by another process running on your machine but you’ll find that it is captured permanently as if it runs on 0.0.0.0:3000 address

**Solution:**

In your project libraries created by **[create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-bootstrap)** script navigate to:

node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js

While running **npm start** command - the **start.js** script is being called and executed

There at **start.js file** in you editor find the above line:

const HOST = process.env.HOST || '0.0.0.0';

and change it to:

const HOST = process.env.HOST || '127.0.0.1';

save and run your web app again at: **http://localhost:3000/ or**  **[http://127.0.0.1:3000](http://127.0.0.1:3000/)**

Comment: editing stuff in node_modules is never a good solution - it is .gitignored so it's not persisted