# listen EACCES: permission denied in windows

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, operating-system, permission-denied

Everything was worked fine before today evening after i uninstalled vscode and installed again I'm facing this issue while try to run `npm run app` i  have no clue how to fix this i tried to run vs code and command prompt or bash using run as administrator but no luck, i see lot of fixes out there for this issue but most of them are for mac they fixed it using `sudo` but i don't see any good fix for windows it would be appreciated much if anyone will help me fix this

```
//this issue this my server code 
const express = require("express");
const app = express()
const port = process.env || 8080

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello");
});



app.listen(port,()=>{
  console.log("running on 8080")
})
```

and this is the complete error

```
events.js:187
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EACCES: permission denied C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;D:\BookStore\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\Samarth's PC\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Users\Samarth's PC\bin;C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3;C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\Library\usr\bin;C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\Library\bin;C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\Scripts;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Users\Samarth's PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin;C:\Users\Samarth's PC\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin;C:\Program Files\heroku\bin;C:\nvm;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Python 3.8;C:\Users\Samarth's PC\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\Samarth's PC\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin;C:\Users\Samarth's PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\vendor_perl;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\core_perl
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1283:19)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1348:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1447:5)
    at Function.listen (D:\BookStore\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:618:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\BookStore\app.js:11:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:10)
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1327:8)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
  code: 'EACCES',
  errno: 'EACCES',
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\npm-lifecycle\\node-gyp-bin;D:\\BookStore\\node_modules\\.bin;C:\\Users\\Samarth's PC\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\mingw64\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\local\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\mingw64\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\bin;C:\\Users\\Samarth's PC\\bin;C:\\ProgramData\\Miniconda3;C:\\ProgramData\\Miniconda3\\Library\\mingw-w64\\bin;C:\\ProgramData\\Miniconda3\\Library\\usr\\bin;C:\\ProgramData\\Miniconda3\\Library\\bin;C:\\ProgramData\\Miniconda3\\Scripts;C:\\Python27;C:\\Python27\\Scripts;C:\\Users\\Samarth's PC\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\python.exe;C:\\Program Files\\nodejs;C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\bin;C:\\WINDOWS\\system32;C:\\WINDOWS;C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\Wbem;C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0;C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\OpenSSH;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Yarn\\bin;C:\\Users\\Samarth's PC\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps;C:\\Program Files\\MongoDB\\Server\\4.0\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\heroku\\bin;C:\\nvm;C:\\Program Files\\nodejs;C:\\Python 3.8;C:\\Users\\Samarth's PC\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm;C:\\Users\\Samarth's PC\\AppData\\Local\\Yarn\\bin;C:\\Users\\Samarth's PC\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\bin\\vendor_perl;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\bin\\core_perl",
  port: -1
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! bookstore@1.0.0 start: `node app.js "app"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the bookstore@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Samarth's PC\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-12-20T16_43_00_131Z-debug.log
```

```
//Error log is here
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start',
1 verbose cli   'app'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.12.0
3 info using node@v12.13.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle bookstore@1.0.0~prestart: bookstore@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle bookstore@1.0.0~start: bookstore@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle bookstore@1.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle bookstore@1.0.0~start: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;D:\BookStore\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\Samarth's PC\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Users\Samarth's PC\bin;C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3;C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\Library\usr\bin;C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\Library\bin;C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\Scripts;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Users\Samarth's PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin;C:\Users\Samarth's PC\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin;C:\Program Files\heroku\bin;C:\nvm;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Python 3.8;C:\Users\Samarth's PC\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\Samarth's PC\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin;C:\Users\Samarth's PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\vendor_perl;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\core_perl
9 verbose lifecycle bookstore@1.0.0~start: CWD: D:\BookStore
10 silly lifecycle bookstore@1.0.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'node app.js "app"' ]
11 silly lifecycle bookstore@1.0.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle bookstore@1.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: bookstore@1.0.0 start: `node app.js "app"`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:210:5)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
14 verbose pkgid bookstore@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd D:\BookStore
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18362
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start" "app"
18 verbose node v12.13.0
19 verbose npm  v6.12.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error bookstore@1.0.0 start: `node app.js "app"`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the bookstore@1.0.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Is there any chance you can paste the error log at C:\Users\Samarth's PC\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-12-20T16_43_00_131Z-debug.log as well?

Comment: I've added the error log also please check @Zhephard

Comment: Are you missing the package.json file? Did you check npm -v or node -v?

Comment: i've checked npm and node version both are in updated versions and yes i've package.json file i see this error is because of some permission issue

Comment: Consider changing the tags for the question as this doesn't imply something to do with node.js or npm, but OS permission management

Comment: it may be but people who have experience in working with node might have a higher chance to give solution this is a very popular issue but unfortunately i didn't get any good and clear fix for this issue especially in windows ,anyways i'll add some extra tags ,Do you know some kind of similar thing for windows like sudo in mac ? @Zhephard

Comment: Use this reference maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9652720/how-to-run-sudo-command-in-windows

Answer (score 122):

Hi anyone who comes here and don't find any answer. I have an answer that I think will help. it fixed the issue for me.
there is cases where nothing is running on the port but some applications or even your code can not run the fix to this is in this order:

1. Open PowerShell as Admin.
2. stop winnat with command below:

```
$ net stop winnat
```

3. start winnat again with command below:

```
$ net start winnat
```

this fixed the problem for me in many cases. no restart needed. I hope it will help you too.

Edit:
I dig in the problem and found out the problem is the port isn't closed in the right way that could be caused easily based on killing the terminal window or the app running on the port.

Comment: This is still working in 2021. Thank you very much.

Comment: Just used it successfully under windows 11 - would have never found that myself...

Comment: Works in 2022 as well. Thanks.

Comment: Please, could you provide more details about winnat? I am very curious

Comment: Works in 2023! 
(the question, however, is why should we have to do this in the first place)

Comment: Implications could be that WSL2 won't work or Hyper-V if you`re using them. https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/9418

Comment: Works in 2024! Thanks, no restart needed

Answer (score 10):

For my case in the env file, I added a semicolon that wasn't supposed to be added
I had written

```
PORT=5000;
```

instead of

```
PORT=5000
```

Comment: Same here. Auto-formatting added a semicolon where it shouldn't have been placed.

Comment: Wohh, it finally worked, Thank you so much !!

Comment: This was the issue for me!

Answer (score 5):

For me this is constantly happening when Windows 10 has some pending updates. To fix this i need to install all pending updates and reboot 1-2 times during the process.

Comment: The same for me. Updates blocking some ports. I didnt find any hidden rule for port blocking in Windows.

Answer (score 2):

> Error: listen EACCES: permission denied

This might be happening because port or your localhost is running some other application on it. One possible error people didn't answer here is an active IIS server in your local computer. In my case, this was the source of error. So I stopped IIS server to free that localhost and it worked for me. In case anyone's facing this problem you may try this option.

Comment: That worked for me.  Changed port from 80 to 8080 and it started right up.

Answer (score 1):

I found that putting semicolon in .env file is making the problem.
Now, I fixed it.
Thanks

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

As in my case, I'd like to leave comments during coding so before this was my line in .env file
PORT=5000// starting port of server

But then I removed the comment and I don't have this problem again

My line looks like this

PORT=5000

The reason is .env file is not a javascript file but a text file. So when using variable from .env file it first considered the port number as
'5000// starting port of server'
So in .env file we have to keep the attribute and the value only

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

### Warning: Don't stop any program, things are there for your security.

`EACESS` is only thrown when you don't have access to the port you want to use, unlike Linux, windows probably has more PORTs that require administrative privileges, 3000 might just be one of them, even if it's not being used, so increase your port number a little bit, add one more zero.

as mentioned by another user - that up to `3016` are being used for administrative purposes, so you can use them, the first address near `3000` you can use is `3017`

```
C:\Users\thisisMe> netsh interface ipv4 show excludedportrange protocol=tcp

Protocol tcp Port Exclusion Ranges

Start Port    End Port
----------    --------
      2917        3016
      3047        3146
      5357        5357
     14645       14744
     48752       48851
     49052       49151
     49252       49351
     50000       50059     *

* - Administered port exclusions.
```

Comment: Such an underrated answer. This is the actual issue being addressed. Just know which ports need admin privileges instead of just hacking blindly at my machine until it works.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this doing these steps:

Always using administrative previlegies

- Install WSL integration on windows
- Run WSL on terminal, you will send to and linux enviroment
- Install node (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-20-04-pt)
- go to the path of your project and execute again using linux terminal

And it will work

Answer (score 0):

I've disabled the anti-virus real-time-protection and it has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue. Some windows application running on the background or perhaps a process that you have started on your own is using the port that you want to listen at.
Try to use a random port number. For example 5645. If you do not get it working after 2 or 3 attempts you can be sure that the problem is not caused because of the port being used.

Answer (score 0):

for me, I had to remove all lock files (`yarn.lock` or `package-lock.json`) and `node_modules` folder. I actually couldn't remove normally the node_module folder so I open Powershell as admin in the directory and run `rm node_modules`and confirmed. after that, I run `yarn install`(it would work same with npm) successfully.

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps someone else, it was failing for me because I tried adding a port that was too small (999), try changing your port and see if it can be solved that way.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen multiple solutions in the internet but its a very simple mistake that I have done.

In the .env file I have wrote the port number like,

```
PORT = 5000;
```

but it should be like

```
PORT = 5000
```

No semicolon ; at the end in the .env file

Answer (score 0):

for me restarting host network service solves EACCESS issue temporarily. I even created an bat script for this issue!

```
sc stop HNS
sc start HNS
```

Answer (score -1):

In this particular case, it fails because in your code port isn't what you think it is. See, `process.env` is an object with your environment variables, not the port number.

So instead of

```js
const port = process.env || 8080
```

It should be something like

```js
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080
```

I figured because I inverted port and host arguments in `app.listen(PORT, HOST, callback)` and found this question while searching why it was failing to start with message `Error: listen EACCES: permission denied localhost`.

Answer (score -3):

Try this steps

- Run your command prompt / powershell as administrator before running
  this script
- Remove node_modules folder completely & reinstall
  dependencies using npm install & then run start script