# npm start reports "Something is already running on port XXX" no matter what XXX is

Tags: node.js, reactjs, port

I am trying to npm start my web app's frontend, and npm start gives me following:

```
Something is already running on port 3000.
```

I tried `lsof -i :3000` and nothing's running on 3000. I tried modifying `package.json` to change to another port to start my app, but it still says `Something is already running on port XXX` no matter what that port is, 3000, 30006, or anything. If I point my browser to localhost:XXX it will just say ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED because nothing's running there.

I'm pretty sure it's not the code's problem because the app can be started on another machine. Anyway, really desperate for suggestions here. I pasted my package.json as follows:

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.10.0",
    "react": "^16.5.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.0",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "PORT=30006 react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3001",
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js Port 3000 already in use but it actually isn't?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39322089/node-js-port-3000-already-in-use-but-it-actually-isnt)

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48334685/5310914

Comment: @张枫旸 did the duplicate answer your question?  Let us know if it didn't so your question isn't closed.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for all the comments, actually this answer helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/49520791/7203672.

I literally tried all methods to kill the process or find the process or reinstall the dependecies but it just never occurred to me that this is a problem with my /etc/hosts. And the problem is I have 126.0.0.1 localhost instead of 127.0.0.1, I probably made a typo some days back, I have no idea.

Lessons learned, should've tried every answer under that post before posting the question.