# How To Kill an Open Port Running In React Native (Expo) in Windows

Tags: react-native, npm, expo, npx

The situation here is that we have initiated a server in React Native using `npm start`, `expo start` or other methods and later killed the server using CTRL + C but when you run npm start again you see that the particular port is already being used and it asks if you want to use a different port

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

i think this would help. Basically try to list the ports in use by :

> ```
> $ lsof -i :3000 -t
> 12345
> ```

Then,kill the port, usually (pid) :

> ```
> $ kill 12345
> ```

or, if it doesn't work,try this :

> ```
> $ killall -9 node
> ```

Need further help? please do refer to this link:
[Node.js Port 3000 already in use but it actually isn't?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39322089/node-js-port-3000-already-in-use-but-it-actually-isnt)