# How to solve this => port 8081 already in use error in React native in windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, metro-bundler

**error listen eaddrinuse: address already in use :::8081

Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::8081**

> ```
> at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1372:16)  
> at listenInCluster (node:net:1420:12)  
> at Server.listen (node:net:1508:7)  
> at D:\RND\Mobile\node_modules\metro\src\index.js:164:16  
> at new Promise (<anonymous>)  
> at Object.exports.runServer (D:\RND\Mobile\node_modules\metro\src\index.js:163:10)  
> at async Object.runServer [as func] (D:\RND\Mobile\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-plugin-metro\build\commands\start\runServer.js:121:26)
> at async Command.handleAction (D:\RND\Mobile\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:192:9)
> ```
>
> **info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node.js Port 3000 already in use but it actually isn't?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39322089/node-js-port-3000-already-in-use-but-it-actually-isnt)

Answer (score 1):

You have an active process on that port

You should either change the port or find and kill the active process

```
netstat -aon | find "8081"
```

and when you find the PID of the process you can do

```
taskkill /F /PID <PID>
```

Comment: if i run this command in vscode it shows:    $ netstat -aon | find "8081"
find: ‘8081’: No such file or directory

Comment: those are command for the windows terminal I don't know what kind of terminal vscode uses. Try those command in the command prompt or windows powershell

Comment: yes this command works in command prompt, thanks for your support