# How do I fix Azure App Service Erroring on Port 80?

Tags: node.js, azure, express, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice

I'm an Azure App Service noob - I thought it would be pretty much turnkey, but I'm having some port issues it looks like. I've deployed a Node/Express web app to App Service...

When I designate the port to 80 in my Node/Express app and deploy, I can't reach the website. When I go into console and `node app.js`, I get the error "Error: listen eacces: permission denied 0.0.0.0:80"

When I've used 3000, I get an error that states something else is listening on 3000.

Am I designating incorrect ports? Documentation seems to say that 80 is one of two ports to use with Azure App Service. How do I fix this error or what is the correct port to use?

Thank you

Edit: This running on Windows inside of Azure App Service

Answer (score 1):

> When I go into console and `node app.js`, I get the error "Error: listen eacces: permission denied 0.0.0.0:80"

The error indicates that the app is trying to listen on port 80, which requires elevated privileges.

- In Azure App Service, the port provided by the PORT environment variable should be used.
- This environment variable can be found in the script bin/www in your generated Express app as shown below:

```js
var  port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);
```

To fix the issue, you can change the port in your Node/Express app to use the PORT environment variable.
You can also check if there is another process running on port 3000 by running the below command as mentioned in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45130296/19991670):

```
netstat -ano | findstr :3000------> To check if any process running
tskill <Process_ID>------>to kill the process
```

If there is another process running on port 3000, you can either stop that process or use a different port in your Node/Express app.

---

*I have created a sample nodejs/expressjs application to check in my environment.*
Server code:

```js
var  express = require('express');
var  app = express();  
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
res.send('Hello World!');
});

var  port = process.env.PORT || 3000;  
app.listen(port, function () {
console.log('Example app listening on port ' + port + '!');
});
```

**Result:**

*Running the app in port 80:*
[image]
[image]

*Running the app in port 3000:*
[image]
[image]

**Portal:**
[image]