i keep getting " listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::1000 " for every single port i use
Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::1000
at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1751:16)
at listenInCluster (node:net:1799:12)
at Server.listen (node:net:1887:7)
at Function.listen (/Users/sithumsitharakariyawasam/Desktop/source codes/         ===+++++++====/POS-Backend/Ts-backend/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:635:24)
at Object. (/Users/sithumsitharakariyawasam/Desktop/source codes/         ===+++++++====/POS-Backend/Ts-backend/src/index.ts:37:5)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
at Module.m._compile (/Users/sithumsitharakariyawasam/Desktop/source codes/         ===+++++++====/POS-Backend/Ts-backend/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1618:23)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
at Object.require.extensions. [as .ts] (/Users/sithumsitharakariyawasam/Desktop/source codes/         ===+++++++====/POS-Backend/Ts-backend/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1621:12)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32) {
code: 'EADDRINUSE',
errno: -48,
syscall: 'listen',
address: '::',
port: 1000
}
i am using   mac  os   sonoma
i tried  using  different  ports  but same results
kill -9  $( ps -ae | grep 'node' | awk '{print $1}')

I have had this problem before, the first time I had been accidentally booting something else on the ports:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67684988/19573911
The other time I was simply attempting to start before everything had fully stopped, adding some patience worked in that instance:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56929920/19573911
